# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'

Tags: python, anaconda, caffe, pycaffe, libtiff

I am facing with an error in caffe installation:

```
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable caffe
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable caffe-fp16.bin
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/build.make:111: recipe for target 'tools/caffe' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/caffe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:536: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/CMakeFiles/caffe-fp16.bin.dir/build.make:111: recipe for target 'tools/caffe-fp16.bin' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/caffe-fp16.bin] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:498: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/caffe-fp16.bin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe-fp16.bin.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
(testcaffe) ebb@ebb-XPS-8920:~/caffe-models/caffe-opencl/build$ make clean
(testcaffe) ebb@ebb-XPS-8920:~/caffe-models/caffe-opencl/build$ locate libtiff.so
/home/ebb/anaconda2/envs/testcaffe/lib/libtiff.so
/home/ebb/anaconda2/envs/testcaffe/lib/libtiff.so.5
/home/ebb/anaconda2/envs/testcaffe/lib/libtiff.so.5.2.6
/home/ebb/anaconda2/lib/libtiff.so
/home/ebb/anaconda2/lib/libtiff.so.5
/home/ebb/anaconda2/lib/libtiff.so.5.3.0
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.8-1/lib/libtiff.so
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.8-1/lib/libtiff.so.5
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.8-1/lib/libtiff.so.5.2.6
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-h28f6b97_0/lib/libtiff.so
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-h28f6b97_0/lib/libtiff.so.5
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-h28f6b97_0/lib/libtiff.so.5.3.0
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-he85c1e1_1/lib/libtiff.so
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-he85c1e1_1/lib/libtiff.so.5
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-he85c1e1_1/lib/libtiff.so.5.3.0
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-intel_2/lib/libtiff.so
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-intel_2/lib/libtiff.so.5
/home/ebb/anaconda2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-intel_2/lib/libtiff.so.5.3.0
/opt/intel/intelpython2/lib/libtiff.so
/opt/intel/intelpython2/lib/libtiff.so.5
/opt/intel/intelpython2/lib/libtiff.so.5.3.0
/opt/intel/intelpython2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-intel_2/lib/libtiff.so
/opt/intel/intelpython2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-intel_2/lib/libtiff.so.5
/opt/intel/intelpython2/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.9-intel_2/lib/libtiff.so.5.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5.0.5
```

users has suggested uninstalling libtiff from `conda uninstall libtiff`. However the problem is that in I uninstall libtiff from anaconda it will remove scikit-image, pillow, imageio as well. This makes a problem for other installation in the same anaconda environment. I even installed `sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev`
 What do you suggest?

Comment: That's pretty explicit, no? Your OpenCV was compiled against libtiff 4, but you have libtiff 5. Either install a copy of OpenCV compiled against the libraries you have now, or recompile it yourself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how should I install opencv for anaconda? 
what about the other two errors,`//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to uuid_generate@UUID_1.0` and `make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe-fp16.bin.dir/all] Error 2`?

Comment: ...so your libSM is compiled for a different version of libuuid. The `make` error is caused by the others -- fix them and it'll go away.

Comment: As for "how should I install opencv for anaconda?" -- follow the OpenCV project's instructions for building from source.

Comment: ...that said, I'd suggest starting out by uninstalling all the broken binaries from your system. How to do that depends on details of how you installed them -- it's too broad a question to be a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your explanation. but I am not expert. how can I find out which binaries are broken

Comment: `ldd` will report on an individual dynamically-linked executable or library.

Comment: ...that said, if you installed everything with your distro's supported package manager and tools, you should be able to report this as a bug to them. (As soon as you install things using different, non-distro supported tools, or add a repository / package source that they don't support, though, you're on your own).